# php curl: can't access to API

Tags: php, curl, get

I'm getting message:

> Authorization required. Probably you did not provide a valid
>   authorization header, or a session is dead.

```
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Accept: application/json'
            'X-Auth-Token: my token'
        ));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://link.privatbank.ua/api/p24b/statements?stdate=01.07.2016&endate=25.12.2016&showInf" );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
        if ($result->error) {
            prn($result->error);
        }
        prn($result);
```

Im think problems with header. How can i do it correctly?

Comment: Add a authorization header maybe?

Comment: provide proper authentication key to access the API

Comment: put this `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER........`  after   `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);` and check

Comment: @Anant don't working

Comment: @Klaod you have provide the authentication key in the url so only you can access the API

Comment: The website is in russian language, I can't read anything. Why don't you have a look into their API manual how to send the auth stuff correctly? It's not even a PHP problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private APIs generally require an authentication data provided within the data packet you are sending. You might have provided wrong information or implemented it not correctly.